# Simplest way to use wildcard in string replacement?

Tags: php, wildcard

I have the following strings:

```
Johnny arrived at BOB
Peter is at SUSAN
```

I want a function where I can do this:

```
$string = stripWithWildCard("Johnny arrived at BOB", "*at ")
```

$string must equal BOB. Also if I do this:

```
$string = stripWithWildCard("Peter is at SUSAN", "*at ");
```

$string must be equal to SUSAN.

What is the shortest way to do this?

Comment: Why dont you just use regular expressions and replace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression. You substitute `.*` for `*` and replace with the empty string:

```
echo preg_replace('/.*at /', '', 'Johnny arrived at BOB');
```

Keep in mind that if the string `"*at "` is not hardcoded then you also need to quote any characters which have special meaning in regular expressions. So you would have:

```
$find = '*at ';
$find = preg_quote($find, '/');  // "/" is the delimiter used below
$find = str_replace('\*', '.*'); // preg_quote escaped that, unescape and convert

echo preg_replace('/'.$find.'/', '', $input);
```

Comment: What if the the string is "Pat arrived at BOB"?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Then there's ambiguity, but that is not a problem because the ambiguity is inherent in the specification of the question, not in this particular solution. The above will treat the wildcard as it would be treated to match filenames from a shell, which I think is correct because that would be the expectation.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Good point, but for my scenario the "pat" part will never be "pat" or anything that contains "at". :-)